# How to get posts with list of ID from SQL function result?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm newbie in PHP, and I need your advice. Thank you for help!

I'm working with PHP and I need to get posts with image attachment only.
I've wrote sql function:

```
global $wpdb;
$postsID = $wpdb->get_results
("
  SELECT ID
  FROM $wpdb->posts
  WHERE
    post_status = 'publish'
    AND
      ID IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT post_parent
    FROM $wpdb->posts
    WHERE
      post_parent > 0
    AND
      post_type = 'attachment'
    AND
      post_mime_type IN ('image/jpeg', 'image/png')
      )
    ORDER BY post_date DESC
    LIMIT 0 , 5
");
```

Now I want to use results of this function for working with get_posts("p= results of function");

How to connect result with calling this function? I can't understand how to pass a parameter to the function.

Thank you!

UPDATE: As I understood, get_posts not allows me to pass a list of ID, I can to pass only one. How can I get posts if I have a list of ID?

Comment: What is the class of `$wpdb`?

Comment: it used for sql connection, if I understood correctly

Comment: Yes, but what *CLASS* is it? What kind of object? This is important if you want to know how to use the member functions of that class.

Comment: Matt, this is a full description of this object and his class - http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to simply inspect what's being returned by this function, simply include this line after the query is executed:

```
var_dump($postsID);
```

If you want to do *something* with the data, that can be done many ways, but it depends on what, exactly you want to do; there are too many options to go into in this forum.

**UPDATE:** Based on the conversation in the comments below, it looks like you want to pass the keys of the results (`$postsID`) to the $wpdb->get_posts() function.

If `get_posts()` just takes a unique ID as the parameter here's what you have to do:

```
// I'm assuming a simple key=>value pair in your array. Modify your code as needed
foreach($postsID as $id) {
    $result = $wpdb->get_posts($id);

    // code that will do "something" with $result
}
```

**UPDATE 2:** Since `$postsID` looks like this: array(5) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#4015 (23) { ["ID"]=> string(3) "779" ["post_author"]=> string(2) "12" ["post_date"]=> string(19) "2012-07-27 08:53:22" ["post_date_gmt"]=> string(19) "2012-07-27 08:53:22" ["post_content"]=> string(356) "Text" ["post_title"]=> string(58) "Продам 2-к квартиру Русское Поле" ["post_excerpt"]=> string(0) "" ["post_status"]=> string(7) "publish" ["comment_status"]=> string(4) "open" ["ping_status"]=> string(4) "open" ["post_password"]=> string(0) "" ["post_name"]=> string(162) "%d0%bf%d1%80%

You're going to need to take the ID from each object and insert it into a temp array and pass it to `get_posts()`:

```
// $args = array( 'post__in' => array(779,772,768,761,716) ); 
$tempArr = array();
foreach ($postsID as $obj) {
    $tempArr[] = $obj->id;
}

$args = array('post__in' => $tempArr);
$result = $wpdb->get_posts($args);
```

Comment: Thanks for this useful function, it's helps me a lot. But I still don't know how to connect results of SQL procedure with get_posts() function...

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "connect results of SQL procedure"

Comment: I have a array with results. And I need to get IDs from this array and pass them as arguments into get_posts() function.

Comment: OHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH in that case you're asking about array manipulation. I'll edit my answer to help you with that.

Comment: @George you should refer to the wordpress manual on how to work with database query results. I'm not 100% sure how the data is formatted coming from the wpdb object, so my answer could just confuse you further.

Comment: I've found that I should use function like this:

$args = array( 'post__in' => array(779,772,768,761,716) );
$post_content = get_posts($args);

How can I get array with ID from $postsID object?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14712/discussion-between-george-and-matt)

Comment: Sorry, chat is not working for me:

array(5) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#4015 (23) { ["ID"]=> string(3) "779" ["post_author"]=> string(2) "12" ["post_date"]=> string(19) "2012-07-27 08:53:22" ["post_date_gmt"]=> string(19) "2012-07-27 08:53:22" ["post_content"]=> string(356) "Text" ["post_title"]=> string(58) "Продам 2-к квартиру Русское Поле" ["post_excerpt"]=> string(0) "" ["post_status"]=> string(7) "publish" ["comment_status"]=> string(4) "open" ["ping_status"]=> string(4) "open" ["post_password"]=> string(0) "" ["post_name"]=> string(162) "%d0%bf%d1%80%

Comment: Matt, Thank you a lot. Today I tryied again, and found that your code not works for me just because "$obj->id;"

It should be "$obj->ID;"

Thanks, you helps me a lot!